# How to read facebook feeds using json format in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, feed

This is my fee url in json format [here](https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=397319800348866&format=json)

I want to know how to get the post content,title,likes,comment using jquery getJSON method.
Any help woulld be appricated ?

JQUERY CODE

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=397319800348866&format=json", function(data) {
        $("#div-my-table").text("<table>");
        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
            $("#div-my-table").append("<tr><td>" + item.EncoderName + "</td><td>" + item.EncoderStatus + "</td></tr>");
        });
        $("#div-my-table").append("</table>");
    });
});
```

HTML CODE

```
<table id="div-my-table">
    <tr><td></td></tr>
     <tr><td></td></tr>
     <tr><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery getJSON() with a callback=? so it will use JSONP.
You must use some api like graph graph.facebook.com
Something like the below.

```
$.getJSON('https://graph.facebook.com/397319800348866?callback=?', function(data) {
     console.log(data);
     $('#likes').text(data.likes);

})
.success(function() { console.log('success'); })
.error(function() { console.log('error'); })
.complete(function() { console.log('complete'); });​
```

HTML

```
 likes: <div id='likes'></div>​
```

Comment: I just tried it out and edited it. It works. Please see http://jsfiddle.net/Doinkmeister/abWwb/

Comment: Just press F12 in Chrome and go to console to see the output.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, as the feed is at a different domain to the one you'll be running your Javascript on and you can't do cross-domain requests with AJAX.

You'll need to implement a server-side solution using PHP or similar to fetch the data and regurgitate it as JSON and then use your AJAX to load your local, same-domain script.

Comment: So how to do it with php ?

Comment: flicker is using JSONP and not JSON. Use callback=? to make use of JSONP. Not sure if Facebook supports it though.

Comment: Just an update. It does work for facebook if you the callback=? Read the following page for more info. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/